# How to format float to integer if the value is integral. That is, display 13.0 as 13 but 13.5 as 13.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, number-formatting

[Working with Python 3.x]

I'm trying to display 2D line equations. I'm assuming the coefficents or constants to be float because it's possible they can be float. However, if they are integers, I'd like to show them as integers.

That is, instead of

> x + 3.0y = 13.0

I want to display

> x + 3y = 13

However,

> x + 3.5y = 13.5

should stay as is.

How do I do this kind of conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

Assumming the function for that will only be passed an exact multiplier (without unknown variable), input and output are strings:

```
def simplifyFloat(str):
    f = float(str)
    if f % 1 == 0: #if f has some floating point this is going to be false
        f = int(f)
    return str(f)
```

And usage:

```
equation = '2.0x + 3.5y + 2'
x_part, o, y_part, o, const_part = equation.split(' ') # o variables for dumping operators

# [:-1] before string means you get rid of the last letter, which is 'x' and 'y'
print(simplifyFloat(x_part[:-1])) # output '2'
print(simplifyFloat(y_part)[:-1]) # output '3.5'
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient ways to do that, but branching with `ceil` value works correctly:

```
import math

number1 = 3.0
number2 = 3.5

def integral_formatting(n):
    return n if n != math.ceil(n) else math.ceil(n)
```

```
>>> integral_formatting(number1)
3
>>> integral_formatting(number2)
3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way I can come up with, is to make a function that returns integer or float, depending on the case. The function can be like

```
def check(x):
    if int(x) == x:
        return int(x)
    else:
        return float(x)
```

Now, any number can be put in equation as `check(1.0) * x + check(13) * y = check(13.5)`. This will result in `1x + 13y = 13.5`. Hope this helps!